# Unity 3D not working any more after update and crash, OpenGL VMware related?

Tags: unity, compiz, intel-graphics

**I know similar questions have been asked a lot of times**, but after spending like 8 hours testing solutions (not working) and reinstalling or reseting drivers/unity/compiz etc... I decided to expose my own problem:

**Context:**

Recently, I decided to upgrade OpenGL (needed for an application) and got a power cut (Quite unlucky).

After reboot: lots of corrupted files and packages, so I had to spend hours reinstalling packages and setting everything up from a tty (no more GUI). I also decided to upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 (not clever I guess) and ... power cut again (never happens normaly but it seems they were working on the electricity grid and I wasn't notified ...)

Anyway, I managed to get my ubuntu working again (It was booting through recovery mode: some graphics drivers not loaded, then "normally" after adding `nomodeset` to grub)

But since then:

- Unity 3D is not working (even if enabled)
- Compiz uses tons of CPU (50% --> 140% on four cores)
  This point is a currently open bug (on launchpad)
- Transparency level not taken into accout for laucher only.

**Some commands results:**

Graphics:

```
glxinfo | grep -i string

server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

Unity 3D not supported:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p 

OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

I have a lots of drivers installed, not sure it's normal:

```
dpkg -l | grep xorg-video

ii  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus                           1:1.5.2+git20140806.f0d278b4-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- Cirrus display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev                            1:0.4.4+git20140806.2673e727-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-geode                            2.11.16-4                                              i386         X.Org X server -- Geode GX2/LX display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                            2:2.99.917+git20150401.61d2baa4-0ubuntu0sarvatt~utopic i386         X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mach64                           6.9.4+git20140806.e538ff6b-0ubuntu0sarvatt             i386         X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mga                              1:1.6.3+git20140806.132dee02-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- MGA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting                      0.9.0+git20140806.1e4cb922-0ubuntu0sarvatt             i386         X.Org X server -- Generic modesetting driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic                         1:1.2.8+git20140806.74a9a343-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                          1:1.0.11+git20150318.d29d8baa-0ubuntu0sarvatt~utopic   i386         X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome                       1:0.3.3-1build2                                        i386         X.Org X server -- VIA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                              0.1.1-0ubuntu4                                         i386         X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-r128                             6.9.2+git20140806.6dc5e9ab-0ubuntu0sarvatt             i386         X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-s3                               1:0.6.5+git20140806.ed0fbfd2-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- legacy S3 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-savage                           1:2.3.7+git20140806.d28cd83c-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- Savage display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion                    1:1.7.7-2build2                                        i386         X.Org X server -- SiliconMotion display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb                           1:0.9.6+git20140806.293d0902-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx                             1:1.4.5-1build2                                        i386         X.Org X server -- tdfx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-trident                          1:1.3.6+git20140806.562c38ca-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- Trident display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa                             1:2.3.3+git20140806.e36a0a8b-0ubuntu0sarvatt           i386         X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware                           1:13.0.2+git20140804.0a596fd0-0ubuntu0sarvatt2         i386         X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

I saw the problem may be due to VMware OpenGL being used, but I'm not sure I can safely remove it ...
If you have any idea I would appreciate